# excel javascript api add-in window pane opens in default browser, not in window pane

Tags: javascript, excel, api, browser, office-store

I have written a javascript api add-in for Excel.  It has been performing very well for 2 years, but now some computers seem to open the panel in the default browser instead of the add-in window pane.  I have only seen this happen on 2 computers so far, but it is a big worry as that is 2 in a week.

I have Excel V1906 and it performs as expected (stays in the pane), but on a clients computer they have V1906 too and it opens in the default browser (unexpected.)

I have run through all the default settings in Excel, checking like for like.  I have tried changing the default browser and it always pops up in whatever the default browser is.  I know the javascript api uses Internet Explorer.  I am wondering if it is some sort of frame or cross domain issue or something like that, but what is strange is my computer and other clients are fine, but some are not, so it doesn't feel like a coding issue, but more a windows setting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Further to the above, I have removed all the .js information, so it is simply an html page and it still pops up in a new window, so nothing to do with the code.  The domain does have an ssl certificate, but the window that is popping up is not showing the s.  It is going to http:

Comment: I have checked the xml manifest file and all js and html files etc and everything says https:.  I have right clicked on the pane in the computer that is working and it says http: for the security information, not https.  So something is changing from https to http somewhere.  I have looked through all of the code and there is nothing that would do this.

Comment: It feels like the manifest file is wrong, but you can't submit a manifest file without https